# creating a grids of squares (2D) in opengl using c++

Tags: c++, image, opengl, image-segmentation

I want to make a square (2D) by using several smaller squares(like a grid).  I need to do this because I want to texture an image on the main square and divide the picture into several pixels(the said smaller squares).

Here's the program:-

```
int h=1,w=1;
int res=25;// res is the number of smaller squares I want
float hratio=h/res;
float wratio=w/res;

void Draw()
{
float x,y;

for(y=-.5;y<=h;y+=h/res)
 {  
   for(x=-.5;x<=w;x+=w/res)
     {  
        glColor3f(1,1,1);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS); 
        glVertex3f(x,y+(h/res),0);
        glVertex3f(x+(w/res),y+(h/res),0);
        glVertex3f(x+(w/res),y,0);
        glVertex3f(x,y,0);
        glEnd();        
    }    
 }  
glFlush();
glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display(void)
{
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
 Draw();   
 glutSwapBuffers();
 glutPostRedisplay();
}


  int main(int iArgc, char** cppArgv)
   {
   glutInit(&iArgc, cppArgv);
   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);    
glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200);   
glutCreateWindow("PIXELS");
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glutDisplayFunc(display);   
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

when I run this program, all I get is a black screen.

Comment: Sigh, yet another "I get a black screen, do my debugging and calculations for me". Disable face culling (`glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE)`). Disable depth test. See if it helps. Print out vertex commits to a file, verify if they are correct. Remove the loop, try drawing just one quad. If one quad works, debug your loop logic. Launch OpenGL debugger and check for GL errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this display function:

```
void display() { 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 

    //set viewport
    glViewport(0, 0, screen.width, screen.height);

    //set projection matrix using intrinsic camera params
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    float aspect = screen.width*1.0/screen.height;
    //gluPerspective is arbitrarily set, you will have to determine these values based
    //on the intrinsic camera parameters
    gluPerspective(60.0f, aspect, 0.1f, 100.0f); 

    //you will have to set modelview matrix using extrinsic camera params
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0); 

    glLoadIdentity();       
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5.0);

    Draw(); 

    glutSwapBuffers();  // Swap the front and back frame buffers (double buffering)
    gluPostRedisplay();
}
```

In your case screen.width is 600 and screen.height is 600.

Comment: Did you try to disable the depth test - try commenting out the line of code in the main that says glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) and also see what happens with glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );

Comment: The problem i believe is that you draw your squares on depth 0. Where you initialise the Vertices make the third argument .... say 10. From gluPerspective() you assign the camera values. In the code I posted above the near clipping frame is at 0.1 and the far clipping frame is at 100.0, which respectfully means that if you want to see any shape on the screen you have to place it between the near and the far clipping frame.

Comment: you see white screen, because your square is with white color :)